# Suggestions required to Parse Log files and store it to dataframe compatible fileformat efficiently

Tags: python, parsing, logging, hdf5, memory-efficient

**Details**

The current logging system contains log lines with timestamp, logtype identifier and then data, which can be list, dictionary or nested data structure of ordinary types. Daily data can be several gigabytes big.

I would like to parse the data and store it in a dataframe compatible file format. Currently I am using HDF5 for that.

**Problem**

1. Current solution using functions provided by pandas are memory inefficient. Is there a better library/solution available which I can use to read the logs and infer types and store it in an efficient way (both memory and time).
2. Is there any alternate solution to HDF5 that I should consider.

Any help to solve this issue is most welcome!

Comment: Store it in a real database of your choice and not an in memory data structure. Anything from sqlite to elastic search will work

Comment: First, HDF5 is NOT an in memory data structure. It can work with very large data sets (NOAA produces 16 TB/day of weather data, and has petabytes archived in HDF5 format). When working with HDF5 data, I have found h5py (with numpy) to be much more memory efficient (and faster) than pandas. They key is a good schema design (data model). If you created the file using pandas, you may be "stuck" with their data model (which is not efficient).